# Why Java regex to recognize select query doesn't find equals part?

Tags: java, regex

In my web application, I need to get a simple select query from user and perform it against database. I want to check this query before executing. so I write a simple regex:

```
(?i)select [a-zA-Z\s]* from [a-zA-Z_\s]*( where [a-zA-Z]*(\s)?=(\s)?'[a-zA-Z]*')?
```

but I don't know why this regex doesn't match to a simple select query.

for instance:

```
 select name from table  where col='@col'
```

the result is:

```
Match: select name from   table  where col
```

Why equals part doesn't recognize by regex?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is missing the `@` of `@col`. I.e. you wrote `'[a-zA-Z]*'` but you need to add `@` to that character set. So `'[@a-zA-Z]*'`. All in all:

```regex
(?i)select [a-zA-Z\s]* from [a-zA-Z_\s]*( where [a-zA-Z]*(\s)?=(\s)?'[@a-zA-Z]*')?
```

Try and play around with it at websites such as: [regex101.com/r/t9x34z/1](https://regex101.com/r/t9x34z/1)

Comment: **Just an observation:** since letter case will be ignored with the mode modifier `(?i)`, all the implications of `A-Z` can be removed from the regex string to shorten it up a little. Since the `*` (match 0 or more) qualifier is used, an empty string in these places will be ***valid***. Perhaps should change this to `{1,}` (match 1 or more) so that at least 1 character must be there. This of course doesn't matter after the WHERE clause `=` character since `''` could be at some point a desired requirement.